# Prove Angles are Equal

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

Vertex $A$ of an acute triangle $ABC$ is connected by a segment with center $O$ of the circumscribed circle from vertex $A$ height $AH$ is drawn. Prove that $\angle BAH = \angle OAC$.

$ $

So I don't get what the question is saying by "connected by a segment with center $O$ of the circumscribed circle". Is it saying that inside of the triangle, there's a circle and vertex $A$ is connected to it? And also, how would I prove this?

Comment: It means:  "Consider the circumcircle for $\Delta ABC$ and let $O$ be its center.  Then form the segment $AO$."

Comment: so does that mean the circle is outside of the triangle or inside?

Comment: Do you know what "circumcircle" mean?  It is the unique circle passing through the three vertices.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle).  You'll need to understand that circle to approach the problem.

Comment: ohhh i was just wondering if the circle was circumscribed outside or inside the triangle

Comment: @pleasehelpme, circumcircle is always outside the triangle, passing through the vertices while incircle is inside the triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**Hint:** $\angle CDA=\angle CBA$ as they are angle that subtend equal arcs. Also, use the fact that $\triangle ACD$ and $\triangle AHB$ are right triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\measuredangle OAC=\frac{1}{2}\left(180^{\circ}-\measuredangle AOC\right)=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle ABC=\measuredangle BAH.$$